# Java Selenium - arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true) scrolls whole page instead of certain DIV

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, scroll

I have the following code that scrolls the whole page down instead of the certain div (I indicated in red color div I want to scroll down) and test fails because webbriver cannot find the element that is hidden under red slider. The code scrolls green slider instead of red slider.

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//html"));
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element);
```

[image]

Comment: you need to target the element with the scrollbar.  Using //html is not going to be it.  Possibly a DIV?  Right-click on the table/grid there and choose "Inspect" to find the element that has a scrollable style set.  (probably an "overflow" setting in the style)

Comment: of course "//html" is an example - there is real xpath. I found locator to overflow element but still your solution does not work

Comment: you'll probably want to use element.scrollBy(x,y)... right now you're using element.scrollIntoView which would be trying to use the main scrollbar to scroll your targeted element into view.  If there's a particular element inside the scrolling div, that you wanted to view, you could use scrollIntoView on it, and it should scroll the parent element.  Also remember that most Selenium methods will automatically scroll elements into view when doing an action on them.

Comment: please add an example, thank you